# Three.js - Mouse hover effect doesn't restore previous color

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating a pattern in `Three.js` and whenever the user intersect with one of the faces with `mouse hover`, it should become gray and when the mouse is moved away from it, it should go back to its original color (light blue). Unluckily this does not happen. This is the part of the code where I think I am having issue:

```
if (intersects.length > 0) {
    if (intersects[0].object != INTERSECTED) {
        if (INTERSECTED) {
            INTERSECTED.face.color.setRGB(INTERSECTED.currentRGB);
        }
        INTERSECTED = intersects[0];
        INTERSECTED.object.currentHex = INTERSECTED.object.material.color.getHex();
        INTERSECTED.face.color.setHex(0x777777);
        INTERSECTED.object.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
    }
} else {
    if (INTERSECTED) {
        INTERSECTED.material.color.setRGB( INTERSECTED.currentRGB );
    }
    INTERSECTED = null;
}
```

I think that the issue with it is that inside the `targetList = []`, since with a `console.log()` I see that nothing is stored inside it.
In **[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ord2rjw5/)**, you can find the complete code. Do you by chance know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: It seems like it's working. When I intersect an existing face, it turns grey.

Comment: The problem is that the other faces should go back to light blue, not black. I edited the question in case I explained myself not properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few problems in your code:

1. You seem to use INTERSECTED.currentRGB to restore previous color. But you never save the previous color into it (maybe the object.currentHex should have done it?)
2. THREE.Color.setRGB takes 3 arguments: (r, g, b). You code wouldn't work even if you saved [r,g,b] to currentRGB, which you can't since there is no THREE.Color.getRGB. In this case, it's better if you use Hex. (THREE.Color.getHex and THREE.Color.setHex)

Here is fixed part of the code, lines changed by me are commented

```
if (intersects.length > 0) {

    if (intersects[0].object != INTERSECTED) {

        if (INTERSECTED) {
            // Use hex rather than RGB (setRGB uses 3 arguments, hex one)
            INTERSECTED.face.color.setHex(INTERSECTED.currentHex);
        }

        INTERSECTED = intersects[0];
        // Save actual color so we can restore it later
        INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.face.color.getHex();
        INTERSECTED.face.color.setHex(0x777777);
        INTERSECTED.object.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;

    }

} else {

    if (INTERSECTED) {
        // Use hex rather than RGB (setRGB uses 3 arguments, hex one)
        INTERSECTED.face.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
    }

    INTERSECTED = null;
}
```

You can see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/ord2rjw5/3/